# Update view without page refresh in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code which runs when a button is clicked.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url+"/controller/method", 
        data: {val: value},
        success: function(data){
            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(data.status === true){ 
                show_notify_message("Success",data.msg,'success');
            } else { 
                  show_notify_message("Error",data.msg,'error');
            }
        }
    });
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<button class='btn btn-xs alert-success' onclick='method(1)'><font color='black'>Take</font></button>
```

Once the changes are made the entire page refreshes and the updated values are seen in the view.

How can I perform the same action without the entire page refreshing?

Comment: do you have a form?

Comment: post more code please!!

Comment: @SouhailBenSlimene this is all the code that I have. I have assigned this function to a onclick event for a button.

Comment: @Krish please post the html and the on click event if you are using a form tag you need to cancel the default action that's  why   i asked for more code

Comment: @SouhailBenSlimene I'm sorry. No I'm not using form. I have updated by question with the HTML code.

Comment: @AlonEitan No I'm not using that.

Comment: @Krish In that case [you should](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) use it, or implement the suggestion in the answer. I personally prefer using `.preventDefault()` because if it was a link (`<a>` tag) then that suggestion would not work

Comment: @AlonEitan the page refreshes even if I add event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 1):

try it this way
**HTML code**

```
<button class='btn btn-xs alert-success' data-method='1'><font color='black'>Take</font></button>
```

**JQuery script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("[data-method]").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     //value from the button
     value=$(this).data("method");
     // ajax call
   });
});
```

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: i hope it helped you :)

Comment: I'm not the OP but if he'll use your suggestion then i'm sure they'll find it useful

Comment: @SouhailBenSlimene Thank you for your help. I will try this and update.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a `<button>` element, set it's type to "button" like this:

```
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
```

for some reason the default type is "submit"

Comment: that did not help.